# Twitter direct message with node js

Tags: node.js, twitter

```
const T = require("./Twit.js");
const stream = T.stream("statuses/filter",{track: '@username'});
  console.log("Start Sending Auto Direct Message");
  stream.on("direct_message", function (eventMsg) {
    //CB function not triggered, When I'm sending messages
    console.log(eventMsg)
})
```

I need to give reply for all who send direct message to my account.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I understand that you want to give a "reply for all who send direct message." Does the code you've posted do that? If not, what does it do? As it stands, your question is very hard to reply to.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted here will never trigger the callback, because the v1.1 `statuses/filter` API only delivers public Tweets, not Direct Messages.

You have two options:

- poll the [`direct_messages/events/list` API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/list-events) to check for new messages every minute or so; or
- use the Account Activity API and to setup a webhook listener which can receive events related to your account (including Direct Messages). You could use something like [autohook](https://dev.to/twitterdev/how-to-build-a-complete-twitter-autoresponder-in-less-than-100-source-lines-of-code-with-autohook-16j0) to make this easier.